# Phonegap volume control(get volume)

Tags: cordova

Phonegap has a setVolume for media api.Now i would like to know is there a way to getVolume().I googled for it and no luck.I found only the setVolume() is there with phonegap media.I think from this point ,i may have to create a new plugin for that.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know `setVolume` for media api doesn't change the volume of the device. It just control the media sound. Suppose device sound is adjusted to 50 out of 100. Then media plugin is considering the 50 only, not total 100.

It'll divide available volume into 0 to 1.0 scale.At the beginning it'll be 1.0 by default. So if you change it to anything else that value you already know. So you don't need the getVolume. Hope I made it clear.

Comment: What about a way to get the current volume of the media?

Comment: Initially it's 1. Then if you change it to some other value, current value will be that one. So you don't need any function to get the current value. Just save the value after changing the media volume. @evolutionxbox